# Change primary key on SQL database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database that I migrated from MySql using SQL Server Migration Assistant and it is now stored in Azure.

SSMA apparently generated a new primary key column, named `ssma$rowid`, for one of the tables. I am trying to change the PK back to Card_Key, but I am getting the following error:

> *An error was encountered while applying the changes.
>
>   An exception occurred while executing the Transact-SQL statement:
>
>   ALTER TABLE [carddb].[Cards] ALTER COLUMN [Card_Key] INT NOT NULL.
>
>   The index 'Card_Key' is dependent on column 'Card_Key'.
>
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Card_Key failed because one or more objects
>
>   access this column.*

How can I make `Card_Key` the PK again?

Comment: Drop the index called `Card_Key` and try again?

Comment: If I do that, I would lose all the values in Card_Key, right?

Comment: If you just drop the index (`drop index ...`) you won't loose any data or values.  You just lose the index that makes querying faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest might be to create a new table [cards2] with the correct primary key and copy your data from [cards] into the new table (just run a INSERT INTO cards2 ... SELECT ... FROM cards). Once that's done, you can drop (or rename to [cardsold] be on the safe side) the original table [cards], and rename the new table as [cards]: sp_rename cards2, cards

This should work.

Comment: This what I ended up doing. I have a feeling that the structure of the new DB (that is born into SQL) will work much better what was auto-converted by SSMA.